# MongoDb: Accessing Collection and console log Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to access a MongoDB Collection and I want to console.log a Object from this Collection.

I connect to my MongoDB as follows:

```
async function main(){
  /**
   * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
   * See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node/ for more details
   */
  const uri = process.env.DB_Port;
  const client = new MongoClient(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

  try {
      // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
      await client.connect();

      // Make the appropriate DB calls
      await  listDatabases(client);

  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
  } finally {
      await client.close();
  }
  
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function listDatabases(client){
  databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

  console.log("Databases:");
  databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
};
```

This console logs:

```
Databases:
 - radiototem
 - test
 - admin
 - local
```

Now I want to access the collection test and console log everything that is inside it. How can I achieve this?

Best regards

Comment: well test is a database not a collection. have you tried `db.listCollections()` is should display all the collections inside that particular db.

Comment: Ah right. But how can I access a particular database and conaole log all entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get items from MongoDB, you first need to access the collection in which they are stored. Collections in MongoDB are basically the same as tables in SQL.

To get a collection, call the `.collection()` function on your DB object you get from `client.db()` with the name of your collection like this:

```
client.db().collection('test');    // This gives you the collection "test"
```

If you want to get items from a collection, you can use the `.find()` method. You can pass it a query parameter which is an object where you define, which items should be selected based on their properties.

Example, get all users named peter from the `users` collection:

```
const db = client.db();
const users = db.collection('users');
const usersNamedPeterCursor = users.find({ name: 'Peter' });
```

Now if you want to get all items from a collection, you can simply use the find method without the query parameter. This will return all items from the collection.

The find method returns a `Cursor` object which lets you interact with the returned data. You can call methods on the `Cursor` object like `max()`, `min()`, `toArray()`, `each()` and many more.

So, if you want to console.log every item in your collection you can do it like this:

```
client.db().collection('test').find().each(function(error, item) {
 // console .log your item or do something else with it
});
```

Comment: your anwer helped me a lot understanding how to use MongoDB. Thanks alot!